# 'flask_bootstrap.Bootstrap object' has no attribute 'load_css'

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, jinja2

I don't know why it can work well at my mac osx, but when I deploy it to my server with happiness :).
 It shows such error:

`jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'flask_bootstrap.Bootstrap object' has no attribute 'load_css'`

Of course I should solve the error first, but more I want to know is how can I avoid such thing. Because I always git commit to test if it works on my server. It's too troublesome and not smart.

PS: I use virtual environment at mac
PPS: [code at  github](https://github.com/Shiqiu2019/wedict/blob/master/myapp.py)

I didn't find the error when google.

1. I expect to use load_css() function.（most important thing now)
2. Find a easy way to make the environment same between my mac(where coding) and linux sever (where deploy)

```
# myapp.py
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
app = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
...
```

```
{# homepage.html #}
{% from 'bootstrap/nav.html' import render_nav_item %}

{% block styles %}
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
{{ bootstrap.load_css() }}
{% endblock %}
{% block scripts %}
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
{{ bootstrap.load_js() }}
{% endblock %}
...
```

````
ERROR:flask.app:Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1834, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1737, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "./myapp.py", line 28, in home
    return render_template('homepage.html',bootstrap = bootstrap)
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 135, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 117, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/templates/homepage.html", line 5, in top-level template code
    {% block styles %}
  File "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/templates/homepage.html", line 7, in block "styles"
    {{ bootstrap.load_css() }}
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'flask_bootstrap.Bootstrap object' has no attribute 'load_css'```
````

Comment: Something wrong with ssh deploy, I think. There is no load_css function in Class Bootstrap at server, but has load_css in my develop env.

Comment: Uninstall flask-bootstrap will be OK